# Find the directional derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For the function $F$, domain $\Omega$, and point on $\partial\Omega$
, find $\partial F / \partial n$.
Function $F(x, y) = (x^{2} + y^{2})$, domain $\Omega = \{(x, y) : x^{2}/4 + y^{2}/9 < 1 \}$, at the
boundary point $p(x_{0}, y_{0}) = (2, 0)$.

What I have:

$\nabla F=(2\hat{x}+2\hat{y})$

$\nabla F(p)=(4,0)$

$\hat{n}=\frac{ \nabla F}{\sqrt{F_{x}^{2}+F_{y}^{2}}} = \frac{4}{2}=2$

So $\partial F / \partial n = (4,0) \times 2= (2,0)$

I know I am doing this wrong, can someone show me how it is done correctly?

Also : $n$ is the outward unit normal and $\partial F / \partial n$ is the directional derivative.

Comment: There is something confusing, what is $x_2, y_2?$

Comment: I am sorry, that was meant to be a square symbol. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing $F = x^2 + y^2$ then $\nabla F = (2x,2y)$.
The normal vector to this region is $(\frac{x}{2},2\frac{y}{9}).$
Evaluating at the point $(2,0)$ we get:
$$\nabla F(2,0) = (4,0)$$ and
$$ n(2,0) = (1,0)$$.
Then, we do the inner product:
$$(\nabla F.n )(2,0) = 4.$$